# How to match partial nest properties passed to toHaveBeenCalledWith?

Tags: jasmine

```
describe("Test", function() {
  it("should pass", function() {

    const callback = (data) => {};
    const callBackSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(callback);

    const createData = (message) => {
      return {
        outerProp: "outerValue",
        nestedObj: {
          message: message,
          prop1: "value1",
          prop2: "value2"
        }
      };
    };

    const someApiCall = (callback) => {
      setTimeout(callback(createData("test1")), 1000);
      setTimeout(callback(createData("test2")), 2000);
      setTimeout(callback(createData("hello world")), 5000);
    };

    someApiCall(callBackSpy);

    expect(callBackSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      jasmine.objectContaining({
        nestedObj: {
          prop1: "hello world"
        }
      })
    );

  });
});
```

I created a spy on a callback function which gets called multiple times with different parameters each time. The parameter is a complex nested object. I am looking for an object with a specific property.

If I specify all the properties like below, it works

```
expect(callBackSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.objectContaining({
    outerProp: "outerValue",
    nestedObj: {
      message: "hello world",
      prop1: "value1",
      prop2: "value2"
    }
  })
);
```

But I don't know full properties. So, I am looking only for a specific property like below

```
expect(callBackSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.objectContaining({
    nestedObj: {
      message: "hello world"
    }
  })
);
```

Is there a way to make this work with a partial match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this.

```
expect(callBackSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.objectContaining({
    nestedObj: jasmine.objectContaining({message: 'hello world'})
  })
);
```

Another way would be to extract the arguments from the method call and test for specific nested attribute.

```
const arguments = callBackSpy.calls.argsFor(0);
expect(arguments[0]['nesedObject']['message'].toBe('hello world');
```